# Get Hyper-V information from Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have an Ubuntu Server (20.04 LTS) running on a Hyper-V host.

But I don't have any information from the Hyper-V host. The only thing that I know is that is effectively a hyper-v host, because my network administrator told me that it is a Hyper-V.

Can I get some information from the Hyper-V from inside my vm? (I have full access to the vm)
For example the hostname or the ip-address? Or where the Hyper-V is running in my network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially within *a container* or *host*, and only have rights to the **instance**, and not the host. Without knowing the credentials, or IP location of your Hyper-V host, you do not have much to go off. Apart from an NMap scan on your logical network, or perhaps checking your `netstat` for communication, you're going to struggle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have only 1 more question: Can I use wireshark to get the IP address from my Hyper-V? Or can I use any other networking tool to get this IP address?